# how to know when start_text_translation_job is completed and what is its status

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Iam using boto3 with python and calling aws translate api start_text_translation_job .
now I want to wait till this call is finished at the amazon end ..

How to know when the call is completed .
Also i will like to know what was the return status of my call

Regards

Comment: Amazon SNS will work. Create SNS topic, subscribe email. Then write publish() in boto3. Or you can use Python module notifypy for browser notification.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the [start_text_translation_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/translate.html#Translate.Client.start_text_translation_job), it will start the job asynchronously and immediately return the Job Id and status for this job.

Response Syntax

```
{
    'JobId': 'string',
    'JobStatus': 'SUBMITTED'|'IN_PROGRESS'|'COMPLETED'|'COMPLETED_WITH_ERROR'|'FAILED'|'STOP_REQUESTED'|'STOPPED'
}
```

You will need to keep polling this job using [describe_text_translation_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/translate.html#Translate.Client.describe_text_translation_job) to check the status of this job. Once it returns status as completed you can get the results by simply using the S3 URI that you used when you created the job.